# becomeFirstResponder not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, ios8.1

I am using UITextField's method becomeFirstResponder to show the keyboard.
This is working in iOS 7. But in iOS 8 this method doesn't show the keyboard.

```
 UITextField *txtAddNew = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,240, 21)];
 txtAddNew.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
 txtAddNew.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
 txtAddNew.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
 txtAddNew.delegate = self;
 txtAddNew.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
 txtAddNew.tag = 15;

 // Open keyboard
 [txtAddNew becomeFirstResponder];
```

Is there any way to do it in iOS 8?

Comment: I don't see you adding that textfield to any view as a subview.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try calling **becomeFirstResponder** like below

```
[txtAddNew performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

As per Apple,

> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder)
>   and the new responder can become first responder.
>
> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the
>   first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if it
>   is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it
>   returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.

Comment: Is weird how this works when [txtAddNew becomeFirstResponder] didn't work in cases.  What is the difference?

Comment: @mskw Probably because calling the selector forces `resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3**

Here is the swift 3 version of the accepted answer. For me to get it to work I also had to add a delay.

```
txtAddNew.perform(
    #selector(becomeFirstResponder), 
    with: nil, 
    afterDelay: 0.1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed the `addsubview` the  `txtAddNew` to the `Mainview`

```
   txtAddNew.tag = 15;
   [self.view addsubview:txtAddNew];  

   // Open keyboard
  [txtAddNew becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your code . i hope it will work

```
[txtAddNew performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 and iOS 11

In my case, no mater what I tried, I was not able to set first responder until I tried this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.isKind(of: YOURTABLEVIEWCELL.self) {
        if let yourCell = cell as? YOURTABLEVIEWCELL{
            yourCell.yourUiTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to first resign the first responder:

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapGesture.rac_gestureSignal().subscribeNext { [weak self] (_) -> Void in
    self?.inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self?.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

self.charViewsContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: this worked for me, is there any Apple documentation that led you to this?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 9.3, the following worked for me:

```
 private var searchTextFieldShouldReturn = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            self.searchTextFieldShouldReturn = false
            self.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.searchTextFieldShouldReturn = true
        self.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.searchTextFieldShouldReturn = true
            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true
        }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            return self.searchTextFieldShouldReturn
        }
```

**So You need to make sure You also implement the textFieldShouldEndEditing delegate.**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others have the same issue as me:

I had an `IBOutlet` connected to my `UITextField`. Erroneously I was initializing this in my `viewDidLoad` method. That is, `[[textField alloc] init];`. I removed this and everything worked again.