# Keyboard turns transparent when becomeFirstResponder() is called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

[image]

[image: After tapping Enter Password]

Hi.
I've wrote a code using fingerprint. When fingerprint fails you can tap "Enter Password" then Password `textField` will `becomeFirstResponder()`. My problem is here: when I tap that button it execute `becomeFirstResponder()` but keyboard
turns transparent. And when you tap on the blank space bottom of Password `textField` it types characters like a normal keyboard. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`becomeFirstResponder()` will not work in this case. Use:

```
yourTextField.perform(
            #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
            with: nil,
            afterDelay: 0.1
        )
```

Refer: [becomeFirstResponder not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098097/becomefirstresponder-not-working-in-ios-8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd tried it with no delay and 0.1 delay worked for me.

Comment: Yes. delay is needed