# Issue in `becomeFirstResponder()` in swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have six `textfields`. Now if all my `textfield` are filled and tap on any `textfield` the it should always put focus on sixth `textfield` & show the keyboard. I have tried below code but it does not show `keyboard` and only put focus when I tap on sixth `textfield`. please tell me what is the issue with this ?

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     textField.inputAccessoryView = emptyView
        if let textOneLength = textFieldOne.text?.length ,let textTwoLength = textFieldTwo.text?.length ,let textThreeLength = textFieldThree.text?.length , let textFourLength = textFieldFour.text?.length,let textFiveLength = textFieldFive.text?.length , let textSixLength = textFieldSix.text?.length {
            if (textOneLength > 0) && (textTwoLength > 0) && (textThreeLength > 0) && (textFourLength > 0) && (textFiveLength > 0) && (textSixLength > 0) {
                self.textFieldSix.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else if (textOneLength <= 0) && (textTwoLength <= 0) && (textThreeLength <= 0) && (textFourLength <= 0) && (textFiveLength <= 0) && (textSixLength <= 0){
                self.textFieldOne.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am sure it is something trivial. Did you debug how conditions are executed? Is becomeFirstResponder being called when you press or not? Is the delegate method itself being called?

Comment: set delegate for all textfeilds

Comment: Delegates are getting called. When I tap on textfield six only then it works.

Comment: debug and check how your conditions work its due to your if statement

Comment: Check whether textFieldSix has an instance or its nil

Comment: First responder is locked at this point in UITextFieldDelegate protocol

Comment: can you try this textField.resignFirstResponder() & then self.textFieldSix.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Please, put your fields into an array. Then the condition can be reduced to `!fields[0 ..< 5].contains { ($0.text ?? "").isEmpty }`.

Answer (score 4):

I think accepted answer is hack. Other thing that we can do is detect `touchDown` on `UITextField`, check if last textField should be in focus and do `becomeFirstResponder()` on it. Next thing, we should disallow focus other textFields if last should be in focus. We can do that in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method.

Here example of `ViewController`. Just connect 3 textFields and all should work as expected (Swift 4):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstTextField.delegate = self
        secondTextField.delegate = self
        thirdTextField.delegate = self

        firstTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTouch(_:)), for: .touchDown)
        secondTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTouch(_:)), for: .touchDown)
        thirdTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTouch(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    }

    @IBAction private func textFieldTouch(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if shouldFocusOnLastTextField {
            thirdTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    private var shouldFocusOnLastTextField: Bool {
        return firstTextField.text?.isEmpty == false && secondTextField.text?.isEmpty == false  && thirdTextField.text?.isEmpty == false
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        guard shouldFocusOnLastTextField else { return true }
        return textField == thirdTextField
    }

}
```

---

Other, more simple way to achieve that check the textField that is going to be focused:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        guard firstTextField.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            secondTextField.text?.isEmpty == false  &&
            thirdTextField.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            textField != thirdTextField else { return true }

        thirdTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: This will work, but way too much work for an easy thing

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that you are trying to assign the first responder when it was already assign to another textField.
The following code should do the trick:

```
extension TestViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let textOneLength = textFieldOne.text?.count ,let textTwoLength = textFieldTwo.text?.count ,let textThreeLength = textFieldThree.text?.count , let textFourLength = textFieldFour.text?.count,let textFiveLength = textFieldFive.text?.count , let textSixLength = textFieldSix.text?.count {
        if (textOneLength > 0) && (textTwoLength > 0) && (textThreeLength > 0) && (textFourLength > 0) && (textFiveLength > 0) && (textSixLength > 0) {

            ///Check if the sixth textField was selected to avoid infinite recursion
            if textFieldSix != textField {
                self.textFieldSix.becomeFirstResponder()
                return false

            }
        } else if (textOneLength <= 0) && (textTwoLength <= 0) && (textThreeLength <= 0) && (textFourLength <= 0) && (textFiveLength <= 0) && (textSixLength <= 0){

            ///Check if the first textField was selected to avoid infinite recursion
            if textFieldOne != textField {
                self.textFieldOne.becomeFirstResponder()
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be work. Are you sure that the simulator has the property to show the keywoard enable?
You can change that property with the keys: Command + Shift + k

Comment: Are you sure that:

1 - ViewController implement the UITextFieldDelegate

"class NAME: UIViewcontroller, UITextFieldDelegate"

2 -  all textFields have a delegate assigned

textFieldOne.delegate = self
textFieldTwo.delegate = self
textFieldThree.delegate = self
textFieldFour.delegate = self
textFieldFive.delegate = self 
textFieldSix.delegate = self

Comment: It's all there what you have written but I don not understand what is the problem

Comment: please, tell me what is your version of swift, so I will do an example for you and I will send it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is strange for me as well but delaying the focus on text field worked for me.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                self.textFieldOne.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
```

I added above code in textFieldDidBeginEdting & it worked like magic.

Comment: Hi, @Techiee. You answer is just a hack. Please, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511309/2463616).

Comment: I think hack saved my lot of time & saved me from writing lot of code. I know my approach is not good.I am going to try your answer

Comment: Technically, in future you can handle bag or even crash because of the delay. Again, check my answer. It's pretty compact and should work ;)

Comment: Do you actually need the delay? In these situations I've just used DispatchQueue.main.async(). To me this is a valid approach to delay the change of focus request until after the textFieldDidBeginEditing has completed, which itself is trying to affect the focus

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'll want to reject attempted edits before they happened; when we wish to reject an attempted edit we will also need to set the sixth textfield as the new first responder.

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textFieldOne.text?.isEmpty == false && textFieldTwo.text?.isEmpty == false  && textFieldThree.text?.isEmpty == false && textFieldFour.text?.isEmpty == false && textFieldFive.text?.isEmpty == false && textFieldSix.text?.isEmpty == false  {
      if textField != textFieldSix {
        textFieldSix.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
      } else {
        return true
      }
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I made something close and have a crash.

Answer (score 0):

**1**  Set UITextfielddelegate in viewcontroller

**2**  Set self delegate to every textfield

**3**  add tag value for every textfield

**4**  add textfield.becomeFirstResponder()

**5**  check if condition using tag for take specify textfield value

Answer (score 0):

Reference to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098244/4990506

> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder)
>   and the new responder can become first responder.
>
> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if
>   it is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it
>   returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.

First set delegate to all field

```
self.textFieldOne.delegate = self
self.textFieldTwo.delegate = self
self.textFieldThree.delegate = self
self.textFieldFour.delegate = self
self.textFieldFive.delegate = self
self.textFieldSix.delegate = self
```

And then delegate

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if self.textFieldOne.hasText ,self.textFieldTwo.hasText ,self.textFieldThree.hasText ,self.textFieldFour.hasText ,self.textFieldFive.hasText ,self.textFieldSix.hasText  {
            textFieldSix.perform(
                #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
                with: nil,
                afterDelay: 0.1
            )
        }else if !self.textFieldOne.hasText ,!self.textFieldTwo.hasText ,!self.textFieldThree.hasText ,!self.textFieldFour.hasText ,!self.textFieldFive.hasText ,!self.textFieldSix.hasText {
            textFieldOne.perform(
                #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
                with: nil,
                afterDelay: 0.1
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To check any textfield use this code

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        print(textField.text!)
    }
}
```

** you can also identify a textfiled by using this -

```
if let txtFieldINeed = self.view.viewWithTag(99) as? UITextField {
    print(txtFieldINeed.text!)
}
```

** then use --
    txtFieldINeed.becomeFirstResponder()

** Make sure to turn on this options -- 
    * iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard
     * Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"